# How to find Launch Path in APK file?

Tags: android, apk, amazon-appstore

Uploaded APK File in Amazon App Developer and got Error - "*Failed to validate launch path. The launch path specifies the starting point of the app that is local to the zip file.*"

[image]

How to get the Launch Path an Android APK. I have tried to unzip the APK.

Answer (score 0):

What tool did you use to build your app? Is your app supposed to be a native Android app or Web app?

Based on your screenshot, you've registered your app as a "Mobile Web" app (aka Web app) on Amazon Developer Console. For Web app, you don't upload an apk. Instead, you upload a .zip file which has a specific folder structure. You can check the [Web app documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/ft-webapp-setup-environment.html) for more info.

If you have an .apk file, you're likely working with a native Android app. In such case, you should create a new "Android" app on Amazon Developer Console in order to upload your APK.

Answer (score 0):

Add your folder name at the beginning. Eg If Your folder name is app.zip, Put app/index.html in the launch path.